# Date Validation failure with Form Binding

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I haven't used Play since the 1.x days and I'm now working on a new app in 2.2 and I simply not able to get a Date field to validate. I have 2 date input fields for this Event form, startDate and endDate, pretty simple.  In the model I am using Joda.DateTime which pulls from the DB and displays in the form with no problem.

My problem comes when I submit again. Something isn't lining up with the formatting I'm sure but for the lie of me I can't figure out what it wants. This is likely due to having almost no Scala knowledge and I'm probably just not figuring out what the correct parameters are..  Heres what I have:

Event.java

```
@Column(name = "event_end_date")
@Formats.DateTime(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
public DateTime eventEndDate;
```

EventController.java

```
Form<Event> filledForm = eventForm.bindFromRequest();
```

events.scala.html

```
 @inputText(eventForm("eventDate"),  Symbol("data-date-format") -> "MM/dd/yyyy") 
 @inputDate(eventForm("eventEndDate"),Symbol("data-date-format") -> "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

In the above I'm trying both inputText and inputDate, I'd like to use @inputDate but I'll take anything that works at this point!  When editing existing data the @inputText displays the date in the "2014-06-06T04:00:00.000-04:00"  format so I know that what I'm adding to the call in the first line is wrong but can't figure out what the parameters are in scala.

On the @inputDate tag It doesnt know what to do with the existing value, I believe so it doesn't display it. Either way when I submit new values in the fields in the "MM/dd/yyy" format they don't validate.

I guess there are 2 questions here.

1. How do I set the date value so it displays when the formats are different?
2. How do I convert the input when the form is submitted so it will validate as a DateTime?

I looked through the form examples and noted that there seems to be  little on dealing with dates and forms. Surprisingly googling has resulted in a a number of very vague suggestions that haven't gotten em anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I did not come up with the solution I was looking for but after a bit of hunting I got the idea to build a FormBean to translate the Model. This allowed me to convert the incoming values when translating the EventForm back to the Event Model and do my date conversions there. Not the ideal solution for this form which is pretty simple. I think this is a good practice though for Form that represent multiple models and/or manages more complex states and metadata not related to the Model.

Reference to the idea is here:  [enter link description here](http://ics-software-engineering.github.io/play-example-form/)

In addition this solved the problem with the @InputDate helper and date formatting where the getter for theEventForm now converts the date into the html5 required format of "yyy-mm-dd". Once in that format the browser (chrome) knows what to do with it and everything displays fine.  I still don't know how best to do the conversion with out the Form backing bean but I'm reading up on Scala now and I have a feeling I'll figure that out with a little more Scala under my belt. I'm already convinced that a basic tut on Scala will benefit Java devs when trying to code scala templates.

Hope this helps out the next scala newbie!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take the date as an input text and validate the date in the form validate method, here's an [example](https://github.com/ics-software-engineering/play-example-form/blob/master/app/views/formdata/StudentFormData.java#L57-123) of such method usage.
If the validation pass then you can convert it into a Date without problem in the controller.